# Perl code to wait for AJAX response in selenium web driver

Tags: ajax, perl, selenium, webdriver

I am using [Selenium::Remote::Driver](http://search.cpan.org/~gchild/Selenium-Remote-Driver-0.11/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm) module for testing webpage,

Can anyone tell me how to wait for the ajax response here.

Answer (score 2):

For jQuery:

```
$driver->execute_script("return jQuery.active")
```

For Prototype:

```
$driver->execute_script("return ajax.activeRequestCount")
```

For Dojo:

```
$driver->execute_script("return dojo.io.XMLHTTPTransport.inFlight.length")
```

An integer will be returned, and if returned value is equal to 0, AJAX request is completed.

```
$count = 0;
while ($count < 20) {
    if ($driver->execute_script("return jQuery.active") == 0) {
        last;
    }
    $count ++;
    sleep(1);
}
```

Don't know perl, so there can be some mistakes. This code will wait 20 seconds for ajax complete.

Answer (score -2):

### ***SOLUTION***

After a long browsing i got the result but not in ajax control...

I am doing some logic in code like waiting for ajax element to present in a page, This solved some of my problem. Following are the urls i referred
[WaitForElementPresent](http://www.seleniumwiki.com/webdriver/using-selenium-waitforelementpresent-in-webdriver/)
[IsElementPresent](http://www.seleniumwiki.com/webdriver/using-selenium-iselementpresent-in-webdriver/)

These links does not contain perl code, but i can do that with methods in [Selenium::Remote::Driver](http://search.cpan.org/~aivaturi/Selenium-Remote-Driver-0.15/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm) module.

Comment: LOL, freaky c# code for `waitForElementPresent` instead of perl code for waiting the ajax response. Nice question and answer :)

Comment: What you need is Explicit waits http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-waits. And your reference contains bad c# code.

Comment: This answer has completely irrelative to the question. The links given in the post has no clue for me.